# Unit testing with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner using only @Component and @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, junit, springjunit4classrunner

I have the following class:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired MyPojo pojo;
}
```

How do i test it without mocking the injected beans? I **do not** have a configuration [XML or declarative].
I have done the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ComponentScan
public class MyClassTest {
    @Autowired MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        this.myClass...()
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do in that test() function. Please elaborate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want use any type of configuration, neither Java nor XML config, you can use `@ContextConfiguration` with your component classes listed:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyPojo.class, MyClass.class })
public class MyClassTest {

    @Autowired 
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // myClass...
    }
}
```

Please note that `MyPojo` class should also be annotated with `@Component`.

However, in the real life scenario you probably will need at least one `@Configuration` class (which can be also used with `@ContextConfiguration`).

Please refer [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing) for more information about Spring integration tests support.

Comment: I ended up adding the classes to ContextConfiguration as you described. As it turns out, for my scenario i do not need a @configuration class as my use case works fine with just components and autowired. I do not have a use in this case for initialization beans.